# Combine multiple files in a directory into one file

Tags: powershell, iteration

My tree view of the directory is as below:

[image]

I want to combine(or assume append) multiple files in a directory into a single file. Meaning, single file in a folder with the combine contents. So, each folder will contain single file with the combined data. I tried with the following approach, however the issue with this approach is it can read only single file in a single iteration.

```
 get-childitem $dir -recurse | where { $_.extension -eq ".json" } | % {
    
    #Combine the files.
}
```

Essentially, I am looking to read all the files in a folder in single iteration. And another folder data into the next iteration. What is the recommended way to do that in the Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have two loops in your requirements that do different things and so it's best if you implement them as distinct loops in the code rather than trying to tackle both jobs with a single recursive loop.

Exactly how to combine JSON files together depends on what the JSON files contain and what makes sense as a combined data structure. For simplicity, I will assume the JSON files that each contain an array of strings and the combined version is just the array concatenation of all the strings for each array.

```
$Source = "C:\Path\To\Data"

foreach ($Directory in (Get-ChildItem $Source)) {

    $Result = @()

    foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem $Directory\*.json)) {
        $Result += Get-Content $File | ConvertFrom-Json
    }

    $Result | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $Directory/Combined.json
}
```

In your example you have only a one level of directories and then each directory containing only JSON files and so the example script reflects that. It wouldn't be hard to modify the script if either of those were multi-level.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the internal cmdlets

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\In'
$items = get-childitem  $dir -recurse -filter '*.json'

$fileOut = Join-Path $dir -ChildPath 'out.txt'

$result = @()

foreach ($item in $items) {

     $result += (Get-Content $item.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json)
    

}
$result | ConvertTo-Json | out-file $fileOut
```

Depending on your requirements and the files you should use:

- an arraylist instead of the powershell arrays for very large (>>1.000) result arrays
- another parser than get-content for very large single files (e.g. the .net methods)

But if this does the job, no need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (untested)

```
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories('S:\SCRIPTS', '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText([System.IO.Path]::Combine($_, 'Output.Json.combo'), # using .combo to avoind merging this output file next run
            ( @([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($_) | 
            Where-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) -like '*.json' } |
            ForEach-Object { [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) } |
            ForEach-Object { ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $_  } ) |
            ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 ),
            [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
     }
```